# Spring Controller does not receive file through RequestBody or RequestParam

Tags: java, spring, controller, postman

I'm trying to upload a file (any type), however I'm doing something wrong, either with the server side (Spring controller) or the client side (postman).

The controller (trying two methods) :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/group")
public class GroupController {

    @PostMapping(value = "/test1", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE, produces = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
    public String testUpload1(@RequestBody MultipartFile file) {

        return null;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/test2", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String testUpload2(@RequestParam(name = "file", required = true) MultipartFile multipartFile) {

        return null;
    }
}
```

The uploader : 
[image: postman]

Comment: Try putting method parameter as "@RequestParam(name = "file") MultipartFile file" instead @RequestBody for the method testUpload1

Comment: I added new answer, please check it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with the following following code.

```
@PostMapping(value = "/test1", consumes = {MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE}, produces = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
    public String testUpload1(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile uploadedFile) {

      System.out.println("Uploaded File Name = " + uploadedFile.getOriginalFilename());
      File file = new File("E:/sure-delete/" + uploadedFile.getOriginalFilename());

    //Upload functionality
      try {
        uploadedFile.transferTo(file);
      } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
        return ResponseEntity.ok("File uploaded successfully ...");
    }
```

Find the screenshot
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! It doesn't work however, the issue remains the same : it doesn't even enter the function due to absent "file" parameter

Answer (score 0):

The issue is related to Spring not having a MultipartResolver bean. Your Postman setup looks good.

If I have no bean defined, I get the following error:

```
[o.s.w.m.s.MissingServletRequestPartException: Required request part 'file' is not present]
```

What you need to do, is to define a CommonsMultipartResolver bean, either in XML:

```
<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <!-- e.g.: 1 MB max upload size -->
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="1048576"/>
</bean>
```

Or do it in Java:

```
@Bean
public MultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
    CommonsMultipartResolver resolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    resolver.setMaxUploadSize(1048576);
    return resolver;
}
```